# Input field cloned through jQuery won't submit

Tags: php, jquery, submit, clone

I have a set of hidden input fields, which are cloned when the page is loaded and/or a button is clicked.

Html:

```
<div class="book_form" id="book_form_hidden">
   <input type="checkbox" name="select" class="sell_checkbox" />
   <h1>ISBN:</h1>
   <input type="text" name="isbn" class="input_large" maxlength="20" />
   <h1>Condition:</h1>
   <input type="text" name="condition" class="input_medium" maxlength="100" />
   <h1>Price:</h1>
   <input type="text" name="price" class="input_price" maxlength="3" />
   <input type="hidden" name="title" value="">
   <input type="hidden" name="author" value="">
   <input type="hidden" name="publisher" value="">
   <input type="hidden" name="thumbnail" value="">
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
function addOne() {
    var clone = $("#book_form_hidden").clone().removeAttr("id");
    clone.find("input").each(function() {
        $(this).attr("name", $(this).attr("name") + "[" + n + "]");
    });
    n++;
    clone.appendTo($("#form_container"));
}
```

When I submit the form and send the data to PHP using a regular submit button, none of the inputs that were created through jQuery are submitted but only the input fields that were initially hidden (and have empty values).

Do I need use AJAX to submit form content that was created dynamically? I am confused.

Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: If I remember corectly I had the same problem some time ago. The problem is that javascript changes the name attr only visibly, not actually in webpage code, so when the form is submitted the input still has the old name (same name as other input). I have solved this problem by actually creating a new input in JS having the name already set.

Comment: #form_container? If the name is right, then are you sure the new inputs are INSIDE the form?

Comment: To clarify what @fdreger is saying (which sounds like the probable answer) if your HTML is `<div id='form_container'><form> ... </form></div>` or similar, you are adding the new elements to the document outside the bounds of the `<form>` so they will not be included with the submitted info. Instead you should switch the elements so the `<div>` is inside the `<form>` like `<form><div id='form_container'> ... </div></form>` (which strict standards say you should do anyway, since an `<input>` should not *technically* be a direct child of a `<form>`, IIRC).

Comment: The inputs are within the form, I just didn't include them in the code sample. I'll give cristy's tip a try. Thanks so much guys, I'll update when it's solved.

Comment: What is `n` inside your each function?

Comment: Sorry; did you solve this after all? I'm not sure I understand Cristy 100% when she says "by actually creating a new input in JS having the name already set". Thanks!